# How to calculate Random Distribution?

Tags: probability, random

I'm pretty sure this is a basic question but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere else.

If I have N objects each given one of M random categories (using a simple uniform random distribution), how do I calculate, on average, the number of categories with at least one object.

I can do this with a brute force method:

SUM m from 1 to M of ((Chance that all objects are in m categories) * m)

This is not feasible for large Ms. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: If $X,Y$ are sets such that $|X|=n, |Y|=m$ you want to pick a random function $f:X\to Y$ and compute the random variable  $K=|f(X)|.$ Then you want the expected value of $K.$

Comment: I believe this will require an inclusion-exclusion argument. Certain, $P(K=k)$ will be an inclusion-exclusion formula, and you want $$\sum_{k=0}^n kP(K=k)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K$ be the random variable for number of non-empty categories.  Let $P_1,P_2,...P_M$ be the probability that group $M$ is non-empty.  By symmetry, $P_1=P_2=...=P_M$, so lets called this shared value $P$.  By linearity of expectation, we have

$E(K) = \sum_{i=1}^M P_i = M\cdot P$

We can calculate $P = 1-(1-\frac{1}{M})^N$, hence

$E(K) = M\cdot (1-(1-\frac{1}{M})^N)$.

If this feels like cheating (because the events of different categories being non-empty are dependent), remember that linearity of expectation holds for dependent variables as well.